# Return a string based on Type, Color and Position

Tags: c#, strings

I recently wrote a really long one-liner, it was really just for fun, but I would like to know if it's bad practice or not. Can you tell me?

Here's my full class, but it's about the `ToString()` method.

```
namespace HGroupBadge.Classes
{
    public class BadgeDetail : BadgePart
    {
        public DetailType Type { get; set; }

        public BadgeDetail(DetailType type, BadgeColor color, BadgePosition position)
        {
            Type = type;
            Color = color;
            Position = position;
        }

        public override string ToString() 
            => ((int)Type > 99 ? "t" : "s") 
            + ((int)Type > 99 ? ((int)Type).ToString().Remove(0, 1) : ((int)Type < 10 ? "0" + (int)Type : "" + (int)Type)) 
            + ((int)Color < 10 ? "0" + (int)Color : "" + (int)Color) 
            + (int)Position;
    }
}
```

It has to return a string similar to `s01137`, when `Type` or `Color` are lower than 10, a leading `0` has to be added because the final string always has to end in 5 digits.  When `Type` is bigger than 99, the first digit has to be cut off. In the end, `Position` has to simply be added to the string.

`DetailType`, `BadgeColor` and `BadgePosition` are `enum`s.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'd be great if you could tell us more about your class/methd. What does it exactly do? You can also add some usage example.

Comment: @t3chb0t Added some description, hope it helps.

Comment: @DainIIIronfoot The only reason I didn't use any intermediate variables is because it would end up being quite a few, which looks really.. long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public override string ToString() 
>     => ((int)Type > 99 ? "t" : "s") 
>     + ((int)Type > 99 ? ((int)Type).ToString().Remove(0, 1) : ((int)Type < 10 ? "0" + (int)Type : "" + (int)Type)) 
>     + ((int)Color < 10 ? "0" + (int)Color : "" + (int)Color) 
>     + (int)Position;
> ```

You definitely should split it in a exactly four methods/variables:

**Method 1**: `GetPrefix`

```
((int)Type > 99 ? "t" : "s")
```

**Method 2**: `FormatSomething`, sorry, I don't know what.

```
((int)Type > 99 ? ((int)Type).ToString().Remove(0, 1) : ((int)Type < 10 ? "0" +  (int)Type : "" + (int)Type))
```

**Method 3**: `FormatColor`:

```
((int)Color < 10 ? "0" + (int)Color : "" + (int)Color)
```

**Method 4**: `FormatPosition` - this might be unnecessary but because all other formattings are method let's make this consistant.

```
(int)Position
```

Finally your `ToString` would look like this:

```
public override ToString() => 
    $"{GetPrefix()}{FormatSomething()}{FormatColor()}{FormatPosition()}"
```

and nobody asks any more questions about what your method is doing.

Comment: Upvoted (for as far as I can do that with this reputation) and accepted. Thanks alot! Here's what my code looks like now: http://ã.co/i/2vf6bk.png and in case you're interested, here's my documentation on how this string is supposed to be constructed: https://github.com/notmika/group-badges#badge-structure

Comment: Oh yay, IDN domain names are not supported on stackexchange :[

Comment: @Metoniem perfect :-) oh, you should also do something about the magic numbers: 99 and 10. If they have any meaning, make them constants.

Comment: Good point. Will do!